# Coded UIT: Assert dispalyTextis always null on Chrome and FF

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new at both automated testing (Coded UIT) and this site so bear with me. I recorded and generated the code for my tests (in C#). I inserted some text assertions that work in IE but fail on FF(ver 27) and Chrome(ver 33). Assert displaytext fail because the value of the field returned is null. Assert InnerText fails because the value returned is Upper case.
Can someone help me resolve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to below link, hope it would help-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx

Comment: Tanks for the hint but unfortunately this does not help me resolve my issue as I can playback the actions in FF and Chrome. The only issue is with the 'asserts' that work in IE but fail in FF and Chrome..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying all the asserts manually so my playback don't all fail on FF and  chrome.I still feel like there's got to be a better to do this as it is very time consuming. Anyway here is an example:

```
public partial class UIMap
{
    public void AssertVancouverBreadCrumb1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlDiv uIBreadcrumbPane = this.UITourScheduleMAAXBathWindow3.UIVancouverBCTourSchedDocument.UIBreadcrumbPane;
        #endregion

        Assert.AreEqual("Home ›  VANCOUVER", uIBreadcrumbPane.InnerText.Trim(), ignoreCase: true);
    }
}
```